# Get Scroll value relative to how much user has scrolled

Tags: javascript, css

I've tried `scrollTop()` on a scrollable element that returns how much the user has scrolled down, but it's relative to the page. What I want to know is, if a user scrolls up 10px then I should get the value *10px scrolled up* and if scrolled down a bit more, then *20px scrolled down*, instead of getting 80px away from the top or bottom. What's the workaround for this?

Comment: The problem here is, that scrolling 10px up does not exist if you have no context. You will have to make your own logic. You can get the initial position and then always calculate to that one. Or you can do it with an interval, based on time. But you need a reference to correlate with your scrolling.
Imagine this: "how fast is this car?" By default you'll go to measure it by the stationary road. This is your relative element you are measuring by. If you don't go by the road, what do you measure by?

Comment: Ahh, you're totally correct @Frizzant Got you...

Comment: @Frizzant is right, since if people are constantly scrolling down, but if the scrollTop() updates every millisecond, then you won't be able to get the exact time. Try setting a previouslyScrolled variable that updates every few secs in a setInterval(), and subtracting previouslyScrolled from currentScroll and do what u want. Then make a logic for showing "x scrolled up" or "down" depending on the polarity of the number